# Add CSS to parent div after checking checkbox in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, onclick

I have a div with a hidden checkbox inside. When you click anywhere in the div, it should tick/untick the checkbox and also add some css to the div.

It works, however it wont work on the first click. After that it is fine.

Any ideas?

```js
$(".panel").on('click', function() {

  var check = $(this).find(':checkbox');

  if (check.prop('checked') == true) {
    check.prop('checked', false);
    $(this).css('opacity', '1');
  } else {
    check.prop('checked', true);
    $(this).css('opacity', '0.2');
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class="panel">
    <hr>
    <input class="check" type="checkbox" name="todo[]" value="1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post your HTML as well please

Comment: you just need to initialize your desired css for the load state either with a class or regular css

Comment: Check this **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/11L4pb1L/)**, does it work for you?

Comment: It works great but sadly not for me. Still have same issue of it not working on the first click. Then after that, it works perfectly....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use .click() on the checkbox to bubble the click.

```js
$(":checkbox").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    if($(this).prop('checked') == true){
        $(".panel").css('opacity', '1');
    }else{
        $(".panel").css('opacity', '0.2');
    }
});

$(".panel").on('click', function(){
    $(":checkbox").click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="panel">
        <hr>
        <input class="check" type="checkbox" name="todo[]" value="1">
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: This would end up in two clicks being fired?

Comment: I added a click on the checkbox. Otherwise the click on the div and the click on the checkbox would cancel eachother out.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly work for me. That's weird.

Maybe you can try with a ready :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Put your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you could be trying to use the on click before the DOM is loaded?

maybe try:

```
$(document).on("click", ".panel", function(e){
    var check = $(this).find(':checkbox'); 

    if(check.prop('checked') == true){
      check.prop('checked', false);
      $(this).css('opacity', '1');
    } else {
      check.prop('checked', true);
      $(this).css('opacity', '0.2');
    }
}
```

Or you could simply put the script after the HTML before the end of your body tag?

Or use the $(document).ready(function(){ .... });

or an auto invoked function like ;(function(){}); etc...

Answer (score 0):

You just need to initialize your desired css for the load state either with a class or regular css –
Here is a solution using classes instead of just css
let me know if it is helpful

Using the document ready ensures that your code is not run until after all dom elements exist you can read more about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".panel").on('click', function() {

    var check = $(this).find(':checkbox');

    if (check.prop('checked') == true) {
      check.prop('checked', false);
      $(this).removeClass('dim');
    } else {
      check.prop('checked', true);
      $(this).addClass('dim');
    }
    console.log(check.prop('checked'));
  });

})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.dim {
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class="panel">
    <hr>
    <input class="check hide" type="checkbox" name="todo[]" value="1">There is a hidden check box here
  </div>
</div>
```